# Set multiple properties inside JS object

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's imagine this JS object as below

```
document: any = {
    id: {
        photo: {},
        required: true
    },
    ph: {
        photo: {},
        required: true
    },
    zp: {
        photo: {},
        required: true
    }
};
```

is there a way to set all `required` properties to false?

Comment: You are talking about setting them without statically traversing the structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the keys out ([Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) loop through each key and change the desired property to desired value

```js
let any = { id: { photo: {}, required: true }, ph: { photo: {},required: true},zp: { photo: {},required: true   }};

Object.keys(any).forEach( e => any[e].required=false)

console.log(any)
```

If you want immutability you can use `reduce` instead of `forEach`

```js
let any = { id: { photo: {}, required: true }, ph: { photo: {},required: true},zp: { photo: {},required: true   }};

let output = Object.keys(any).reduce((op,c) => {
  op[c] = {...any[c],required: false }
  return op
},{})
console.log(output)
```

Comment: in the second example you return a array of objects ,  i think that is wrong to this question case

Answer (score 0):

*I'll answer with JS as I'm not ready with TS:*

```js
const myDocument = {
  id: {
    photo: {},
    required: true,
  },
  ph: {
    photo: {},
    required: true,
  },
  zp: {
    photo: {},
    required: true,
  },
};

Object.keys(myDocument).forEach(key => myDocument[key].required = false);

console.log(myDocument);
```

Comment: This is the same as [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54465307/215552)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use map to change all properties values , and . ow the object go by reference . You don't need to create a new variable.

```js
var  any = {
    id: {
        photo: {},
        required: true
    },
    ph: {
        photo: {},
        required: true
    },
    zp: {
        photo: {},
        required: true
    }
};
Object.keys(any).map(function(key, index) {
  any[key].required =false;
});
console.log(any);
```

Comment: Actually, you create a new array by using `map`; you just do nothing with that array. That's why `map` should not be used for side effects like this, and why there is a `forEach` function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can simply use [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to traverse the object

```js
let any = {
    id: {photo: {}, required: true},
    ph: {photo: {}, required: true},
    zp: {photo: {}, required: true}
};

for (const key in any)
{
    any[key].required = false;
}

console.log(any);
```